# ng-models name collision inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/2UFfaG?p=preview

I used this sample code to build a simple app and I noticed that the edit function doesn't work when you are using ng-models that are repeated in a loop. I know this, because I tried using ng-models outside of the ng-repeat loop and it worked perfectly. So when you have two instances of ng-models with the same name, you get a blank data back when you try to get the values back from the view.

This is my view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="notes in notes">
    <li>
      <span ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing = true">{{note.name}} | {{note.content}}</span>
      <form ng-show="editing" ng-submit="editing = false">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name" ng-required/>
        <label>Content:</label>
        <input type="date" ng-model="content" placeholder="Content" ng-required/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="edit(note.id)">Save</button>
      </form>
    </li>

</ul>
```

This is my edit method:

```
$scope.edit = function (id) {
    var note = notesRef.child(id);
    var newNote= {

            name : $scope.name,
            content : $scope.content

        }
    };

    note.update(newNote);
};
```

When I refer to a ng-model inside of ng-repeat, I can only get the value null for some reason. I get the correct value when I refer to ng-models outside of the ng-repeat for some reason.

How do we solve this problem? What's the simplest solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Can you create a plnkr of your problem not working?

Comment: here, should be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the item belongs to the scope of the repeat.

If you changed your `ng-model` to:

```
<ul ng-repeat="notes in notes">
    <li>
      <span ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing = true">{{note.name}} | {{note.content}}</span>
      <form ng-show="editing" ng-submit="editing = false">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="note.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required/>
        <label>Content:</label>
        <input type="date" ng-model="note.content" placeholder="Content" ng-required/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="edit(note)">Save</button>
      </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where it's now `note.name` / `note.content`.

Then instead of padding the `note.id` to the edit button, you pass in the entire `note` i.e `ng-click="edit(note)"`

Then your controller will get passed the entire note.

```
$scope.edit = function (note) {    
    // send note to server via $http, changes to `note` are already made directly to the note itself
};
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this. As we know ng-repeats directive create their own new scope.

> bday.editing

```
 <ul ng-repeat="bday in bdays">
    <li>
      <span ng-hide="bday.editing" ng-click="bday.editing = true">{{bday.name}} | {{bday.date}}</span>
      <form ng-show="bday.editing" ng-submit="bday.editing = false">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" **ng-model="bday.name"** placeholder="Name" ng-required/>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" **ng-model="bday.date"** placeholder="Date" ng-required/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    </li>

</ul>
```

and here what I understand from your question is that you want to edit only the item on which you have click. this is the solution for the same. 
One more solution for the same problem is that create a new function that take one argument that is "bday". make edit true only for this item and set editing false for all others element. this solution is for that case if user doesn't submit  the form and click on other item.

Comment: No, the issue is that I have several ng-model of the name: bday.name. So, I get null when I try to get the value from the view. It works when I use ng-models outside of the ng-repeat loop.

Comment: @jarvan what do you mean when you get the value from the view? You don't make any sense.

Comment: @bharat all you did was modify the scope of the `ng-repeat` by making the `repeat.editing` to `repeat.bday.editing` the editing belongs to the scope of the repeat not to the variable bday attached to the scope of repeat.

Comment: value from the ng-model that are repeated in the ng-repeat loop     so basically i have like 4 sets of ng-models with the same name in a ng-repeat loop with 4 elements so it doesn't work because of the name collision I think.

Comment: @jarvan you need to give an example of what you're trying to do so we can tell you what's wrong. The repeat has its own scope. There is no collision. The plnkr does not push a new item in for editing. It only pushes a new item to the array when saving a new item.

Comment: @Phill yes I agree with you the scope is belong to repeat. But its just the simple solution for edit true on current element.

Comment: @BharatBhushan the OP hasn't told us what he's trying to do. We need more information to answer his question.